# How do i move MySQL directory to an external network drive in MAC OSX 10.9.4

Tags: mysql, macos

I am new to the database world and I ran into some problems.... 
My hard disk on my Mac says I have less than 8gb left of free space. For this reason, I would like to move my MySQL data directory to an external network drive called `ls-xld4c`. 
I have been trying to follow the rules to do so via http://mailsteward.com/nickstek/?p=22

As noted from step 3 from the link above:
I copied the `/usr/local/mysql/data` directory and all of its files and subdirectories to the
new location at `/Volumes/share/MYSQL`

So here is what i typed in my terminal:

`cd /Volumes/share/MYSQL`

`cp -R /usr/local/mysql/data`

which returns the following: ( i do not know what this means)

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
```

Here is some info that might be handy:

1) `Server version: 5.6.17 MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

2) Where my external drive is located: `/Volumes/share`

-The network drive is called `ls-xld4c` and is 1TB in size(I don't know if that is relevant)
The specific folder I want to put the directory reads that it is found in...
Server : `smb://ls-xld4c/share/MYSQL` , however `/Volumes/share/MYSQL` shows that it is a valid directory

3) I do not have a password and the user is root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost done it. The error is flagged because you have not specified the destination directory which should be your current working directory. Please use CO command as:

```
cp -R /usr/local/mysql/data .
```

The ending dot means current directory which you have already set by using:

```
cd /Volumes/share/MYSQL
```

By the way, the following steps are required:

1. Stop MySQL service.
2. Copy data files from the directory as specified in "my.cnf" or "my.inf" (in case of windows).
3. Paste data to destination dir.
4. Change "my.cnf" or "my.inf" such as the "datadir" entry specifies the destination path.
5. Restart MySQL.

Comment: thanks @Shail for responding. I am having trouble after typing `cp -R /usr/local/mysql/data .` ... I receive a message saying `permission denied` How do i get through this?

Comment: Please check and make sure that you have write-permission on the current working directory that is /Volumes/share/MYSQL and sorry for delay...

Comment: Doesn't work, the server is still pointing to `/usr/local/mysql/data/ `

Answer (score 2):

On macOS Big Sur, MySQL installer used to install MySQL:

1. Go to System Preferences > MySQL > click on Stop MySQL Server
2. In configuration tab, you can see current Data Directory
3. Copy data folder to your destination directory
4. Change "Data Directory" address to your destination address > then Apply
5. Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access and make sure "mysqld" is checked here
6. Go to System Preferences > MySQL > click on Start MySQL Server

if you do not do step 5, the service won't start back.
hope it helps for those with permission issues

Comment: Indeed. very important step 5. Lost a lot of times on that one, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**1. Stop MySQL**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

**2. Change Data Directory**

```
sudo cp -R -p /var/lib/mysql /newlocation
```

**3. Edit MySQL default configuration file**

```
sudo vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
change 'datadir' to /newlocation

sudo vim /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld

change '/var/lib/mysql' two-entries to /newlocation
```

**4. Start MySQL**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```